# Como remover linhas em branco no VS Code?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

Recentemente copiei um arquivo que estava em um servidor e ele veio todo assim, com uma linha em branco entre cada linha de código.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum atalho no [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), ou comando para remover essas linhas vazias pelo **VS Code**, e que seja de forma prática e não manualmente removendo as linhas vazias uma por uma na mão...

```
<!-- BANNER -->

<section id="produtos"  class="container-fluid banner d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

  <div class="row w-100">

    <div class="col-12 text-center pt-1 pt-sm-4">

      <h2 class="tit-banner">TINTAS ESPECIAIS PARA</h2>

      <span id="app" class="texto-banner app"></span>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<!-- Lista Produtos -->

<section class="container mb-4">

  <div class="row mt-5">

    <div class="col-12 text-center">

      <h4 class="sec-h4 mb-3">nossa linha completa de tintas</h4>

      <h2 class="sec-h2">Temos o produto certo para te atender</h2>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>

  ...etc...
```

***OBS:*** Originalmente esse arquivo não era assim, ele não tinha linhas em branco entre as linhas de código, e olhando direto o código fonte da página que está no server também não existem essas linhas vazias...

Comment: isso ai é diferença de sistema operacional, no linux normalmente a quebra é CHR(10) `"\n"` e no Windows CHR(13)+CHR(10) `"\r\n"` que é entendido como duas quebras em outros OSes. Se tiver opção de "abrir como" escolhendo quebra de linha de windows, é pra resolver

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Siga as seguintes passos:

- Pressione <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Selecione "Usar Expressão Regular"
- Caixa de Pesquisa: `^(\s)*$\n`
- Caixa de Substituir: Deixe em branco.
- Clique em Substituir Tudo.

## Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[***Visual Studio Code - delete all blank lines - regex***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350324/visual-studio-code-delete-all-blank-lines-regex/44469675#44469675)</sup>

## Explicação Regex:

- O regex é bem simples, a linha deve começar(`^`) e terminar(`$`) com espaços, ou seja, não deve conter nada na linha!

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: @hugocsl por nada!

Answer (score 0):

O VS Code tem um botão para habilitar Expressões Regulares.

[image: VS Code Regex]

É necessário Ativar para funcionar.